# Sending my passport as part of my Canada visa application

Tags: canada, new-york-city

Please I need a clarification on what to do.

I was asked to submit my passport(s) by mail or in person following the instructions below:

With your passport(s), make sure you include:

- the passport request letter you received from IRCC;
- any applicable visa application centre (VAC) fees, such as passport transmission fees;
- full contact information, including email, phone number, and full return address;
- the VAC consent forms (available on their Web site);
- and a pre-paid return courier envelope, if applicable.

My questions:

1. How much is the passport transmission fee? Which address am I to send it to?
2. Where do I get the VAC consent form?

Comment: Welcome to Travel! I don't know if it matters, but what type of visa are you applying for? Were these instructions in a letter you received or on a website? If a website, which one?

Comment: Hi! Did you figure it out by any chance?

Comment: Here's what I did: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135383/sending-passport-for-canada-visa-process-to-new-york?noredirect=1#comment347033_135383

Answer (score 2):

### This is what I got from the customer service agent in chat on 05-Aug-2022.

If you are located in the United States of America and have received the passport request letter from IRCC (Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada), your passport can be submitted either in person or by courier to the CVAC (Canada Visa Application Center).
Please drop off, or send to the CVAC in a single envelope, all of the following documentation:

1. The passport request letter you received from IRCC.
2. The original and valid passport.
3. Your contact information on a single sheet of paper, including your email, phone number and return mailing address.
4. Two copies of the TT services consent form, second page duly completed and hand signed, the link to download is: https://assets.ctfassets.net/xxg4p8gt3sg6/2LVFqatIwJhm9JEP5nqUYL/3c71a4a1468630ef0845c423a3cd41e2/ConsentForm_-TTS-English-IN-VAC-Final.pdf
5. If you purchase the two-way courier service, do not forget to attach a printed copy of the payment invoice, thrown by the system just at the moment of paying with your card.

Below charges must be paid, by card directly at the CVAC, or in the form of a Money Order or Cashier’s check, in favor of “VFS Services (USA) Inc.” Fees must be in US dollars:

Package transmission(per passport): $22.80 USD (Only if you did not have to provide your biometrics, or if they were taken at a CVAC other than the one where the passport will be sent).

One-Way Courier Service: $37.20 USD* per passport. TT Services/VFS Global has an agreement with FedEx, offering a preferential rate to our customers for the return of their passports, only within the USA. This service is optional, if you do not wish to take advantage of it or if you are not inside the USA, then please include a prepaid shipping label with your passport and documents. FedEx labels will not be accepted.

Short Message Service (SMS) per applicant – $2.50 USD (Optional).

It is recommended to use a padded envelope to mail your documents and make sure it is thoroughly sealed.

To confirm the information provided, please visit our website: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/additional-services

**Los Angeles CVAC mailing Address:**

Canada Visa Application Centre.

8530 Wilshire Blvd, Suite 450.
Beverly Hills, CA 90211.

**New York CVAC mailing Address:**

Canada Visa Application Centre.

145 West 45th street, 4th floor.
New York, NY 10036.

*In person, passport submission and decision envelope collection directly at the Canada Visa Application Centre:

**Los Angeles CVAC**: between 9.00 am to 3:00 pm, Monday through Friday.

**New York CVAC**: between 1.00 pm to 4:00 pm, Monday through Friday.

*To avail the optional two-way courier for $ 75.30 USD (only within USA), please visit: https://www.vfsglobal.ca/PostalAppointment/Account/RegisteredLogin?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/CQ1P0LBKn66dLdNUfueK+wj/xwjQV05sWPtysuvzK33qrK3eXshT1TAgsu3oVBZovxbG4hegjVxPtRK4ehNyPck+V525rUvI5fmDu7unjO/

When accessing the portal, please complete the registration and proceed selecting your preferred center to mail your application.  You can choose between Los Angeles and New York CVAC.
Kindly note that all the information will be purged from the portal after 10 days, your login information included, hence, make sure you print or download your label and confirmation letter as soon as you receive it.
Once you complete the process, you will be able to print the FedEx label (addressed from you to the VAC). The label for the returning of your documents will be created locally at the CVAC.

Comment: **The chat in the VFS global site is pretty handy if you have other questions**:


https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/contact-us#

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I am fuming with anger. Why isn't this list available on their website? The missing/outdated instruction cost me more than a week.

Answer (score 1):

The documents you will need to send are:

1. Passport
2. Passport request letter
3. TT Services Consent Form (2 Copies, For each Passport)
4. A Sheet paper with your contact information (Name, Address, Phone & Email)
5. A prepaid Return envelope from UPS, USPS or DHL (For each Passport)
6. Package transmission USD$19.90 (ALSO for each passport; AND If you took the biometrics on the same centre you are sending the passport ((NY or LA)) you can skip this Fee)

Can deposit Cashier/Banker check or Money order. Payment instruments should be made in favor of “VFS Services (USA) Inc.”

For the concent form you only need to fill the second page, you can leave the others blank, but include them all (4 pages) when you send the passport.

Comment: What should be "Return Address" on return envelope? 


Visa Application Centre, New York City
145 WEST 45th street, 4th floor New York, NY 10036, USA

or 

Consulate General of Canada in New York ?