# Sending Passport to VAC for Canadian Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, canada, vfs-global

This would be a similar question but is quite old: [Sending Passport for Canada Visa Process to New York](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135383/sending-passport-for-canada-visa-process-to-new-york)

I was asked to send my passport to the VAC in either New York or Los Angeles (New York would be closer for me) as part of my Canadian visitor visa application. I got my biometrics done in Austin, TX.

The letter sent by IRCC redirects to the VAC center finder and under the United States, the following are required:

United States of America
Submit your passport at the visa application center

the passport request letter you received from IRCC;
the visa application center (VAC) fees (VACs charge service fees to send your passport to the visa office);
your contact information, including your email, phone number, and return address; and
the VAC consent forms (available on their Web site).

VFS Global website is absolute garbage and their contact number +1-888-296-4511 doesn't connect.

I am therefore confused regarding the following:

1. What are the current transmission fees and how do I send it to VAC?
2. How do I send the return labels? (I saw some confusion regarding FedEx and UPS)

If someone has done this process recently, would appreciate their experience in this area.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am going through a similar process and am having difficulty buying the courier service. It says to use this website https://www.vfsglobal.ca/PostalAppointment/ but i have tried it soooo many times and it does not send a verification to my email. Tried multiple emails, browsers, and spam. Thoughts?

Comment: Following website was useful for courier and other VFS services:
https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/news/reopening-notice

Follow the TTservices link to pay and generate the courier labels for the 2 way courier. You would also need to pay for the handling fees via a money transfer for handling of passport on their end. All information is in the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The up-to-date information is available on https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/apply-visa under "Service charges" tab.

If it is your first recent application to Canada and paid a biometric fee (currently 85 CAD), that fee includes **one** package transmission fee at the same VAC.

If you applied online for a non-transit visa (i.e. you only did biometrics at the VAC and did not submit your application there), you do not have to pay the package transmission fee again if you send the passport to the same centre as your biometrics appointment.

If you send the passport to a different VAC or you have used the included transmission service (between the VAC and the visa office) once already after the biometrics, you will have to pay for the transmission, currently (April 2022)   27.62 CAD or 22.80 USD for VACs in the USA.

Additionally, citing the Covid situation (justified or not), the VACs in the USA currently forces you to use their chosen courier service which means you do not have to prepare the submission label or the return envelope. Unfortunately, the fee for two-way transmission currently stands at 91.27 CAD or 75.30 USD. Currently a 10% discount applies to this fee.

The fees can be paid by certified check or money order. Online payment is possible or even obligatory for the two-way courier fee. You can email them or chat online with them for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I did give my biometrics at Austin so I believe I will have to pay the transmission fee now as well. The courier service is quite the shocker and raises the whole fee by almost $100 overall. But I guess it makes the process simpler as the 2-way courier should be safer and more direct.

So finally, I should only pay for the 2-way courier, transmission fee and prepare the courier with the passport, IRCC letter, letter with address details, and payment money orders and they should take care of it, correct?

Comment: @NikhilSingh There is currently a 10% discount on the courier fee, so it would be ~67 USD instead of 75. You may also need the consent form https://assets.ctfassets.net/xxg4p8gt3sg6/2LVFqatIwJhm9JEP5nqUYL/3c71a4a1468630ef0845c423a3cd41e2/ConsentForm_-TTS-English-IN-VAC-Final.pdf For two-way courier you need to make the labels at https://www.vfsglobal.ca/PostalAppointment/Account/RegisteredLogin?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/CQ1P0LBKn66dLdNUfueK+wj/xwjQV05sWPtysuvzK33qrK3eXshT1TAgsu3oVBZovxbG4hegjVxPtRK4ehNyPck+V525rUvI5fmDu7unjO/ and pay there.

Comment: @NikhilSingh The transmission fee has to be paid by certified check or money order and you can send the check or order with the passport when the courier comes to pick up your documents.

Comment: Thank you @xngtng for all the help

Comment: Also, what's the estimated time for this? Like how soon can I expect to get the passport back and can I track the progress?

Comment: @NikhilSingh I would count at least a week, but shouldn't exceed two weeks (they have to send your passport to the visa office, the visa office stamps it and sends it back to the VAC who then sends it back to you; also holidays e.g. Easter can make things take longer). Sometimes you may even get lucky and have it back in a few days. Good luck.

Comment: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/news/reopening-notice has the correct information for this process

Comment: @NikhilSingh Hi. I am going for the USPS money order option and wanted to know whether to include only the Pay To information or do we need to include the From, Address details too? VFS customer care is saying only to include Pay To and leave everything else as blank. Please confirm. I am really confused!